# Geometry Nodes: How do I center a cube to the bounding box of text

Tags: geometry-nodes

I've created an extruded text with the geometry nodes and tried to use the bounding box caluclations to center a cube. For some reason this isn't working. The centering works fine if I use a another cube instead of the text. Any ideas?

[image: graph]
[image: result]

[image]

I also tried to use just one letter, but this is also not working:
[image: just one letter]

Comment: The Bounding Box node is giving a bounding box for each letter in the curve.

Comment: @MartyFouts I also tried to use just one letter, but this is also not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a [Realize Instances](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/instances/realize_instances.html) Node before the Bounding box to get the bounding box for the entire text. Here's my tree:

[image: Solution]

and here's my result:

[image: Resulting geometry]

Comment: Realize Instances works great, but I can't see why you would subtract the minimum from the maximum. Let's say: xmin=-10 and xmax=20 then the center would be at 5. Adding and dividing results to (xmin+xmax)/2=5, but subtracting to (xmin-xmax)/2=-15.

Comment: You're right.  It should be add not subtract. Fixing my answer now.